# Is there a PHPish way of doing webpages with Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby

Is there a framework or something out there so that I can develop webpages in Ruby the same way I can as PHP. Something like

```
<html><head></head><body>
<?ruby
  puts '<p> Hello there!</p>'
?>
</body></html>
```

The only thing I'm seeing for using Ruby in webpages is huge complex frameworks that is completely different from how PHP works. I mean, sure that's all fine and dandy with the 3 tier model and such but when your just wanting a few simple things done(which are trivial in PHP) in a webpage, to setup such a large framework just doesn't seem right. Especially when you only really want like 1 page made in Ruby and the rest being plain HTML.

Comment: If you want to use PHP, use PHP. Don't try and turn PHP into Ruby. This goes for any other pair of technologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to use erb files directly like PHP files with NGINX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481501/is-there-a-simple-way-to-use-erb-files-directly-like-php-files-with-nginx)

Comment: @cletus that makes no sense in this case, because Ruby and PHP language domains almost completely overlap. The seasoned developer implicit motto, "learn everything as I did" with the typical choir of applauding nodders is so boring. Looking into integrating Ruby in a HTML file quickly and simply as with PHP is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two words: [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) and [ERB](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html)

(For lightweight sites, at least).

Sinatra is a simple HTTP server, ERB is a templating system that acts similar to templating in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

The default behavior for PHP is to run as CGI scripts, which means that the web server calls `php-cgi <path/to/php-script>` or something similar, passing quite a lot of environment variables. To do the same with Ruby, you need to setup a script to handle .rb files. This varies wildly depending on your web server, but if you are using Apache 2.2, put this in your httpd.conf or .htaccess file:

```
Action ruby-cgi /path/to/ruby-cgi
AddHandler ruby-cgi .rb
# You might want to add this too:
DirectoryIndex index.rb index.html
```

You could either specify the path to your ruby executable (run `which ruby` to get the path), or to any other script that accepts a filename as the first parameter. If you use the ruby executable, nothing magical happens, and you can't insert erb into the file without adding some ERB compiling yourself. However, you could use my [`ruby-cgi`](http://gist.github.com/256121) script, which does several things:

- First, it takes the file and interprets it as ERB, this make the syntax look more like PHP (see below for an example).
- Second, it initializes the CGI object into the global variable `$CGI`. See below for an example on how to use this.

This is a simple example script on how you can use the `ruby-cgi` "magic":

```
<% header "Content-Type" => "text/html" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= $CGI['title'] %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= $CGI['title'] %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let's say you put this into the webroot with the name `example.rb`. If you then access this with a URL similar to http://example.com/example.rb?title=Hello%20world it should set the title to "Hello world", and it should display a <h1> with "Hello world" in it.

If you find any bugs with the script, feel free to fork the gist and update it.

Comment: That looks really nice. What license is that under?

Comment: Oops, I keep forgetting to add licensing to my stuff. It's under the MIT License (I added the license part to the code now).

Comment: FWIW, here's my working `httpd.conf`, `ruby-cgi.rb`, and an example erb file from my experimentation with ruby 1.9.3 and Apache 2.2.20: https://gist.github.com/1860123

Comment: Isn't there yet a big, maintained project in the Ruby community for this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/)? It is very simple ruby compiler that outputs static pages through a template engine. May be too simple for your needs but it is handy some times.

Answer (score 0):

You can, with https://github.com/migrs/rack-server-pages

Instruction at that page.

Summarizing:

- gem install `rack-server-pages`
- Create `config.ru` in the root folder of your "application":

  `require 'rack-server-pages'
   run Rack::ServerPages`
- Create public/index.erb:

  `<h1>Hello rack!</h1>
   <p><%= Time.now %></p>`
- execute `rackup`, your Ruby powered pages are ready to be served.
- **It also works with other application servers**, for example, for passenger standalone, you just need to go to that folder and run `passenger start`.