# Is there a simple way to use erb files directly like PHP files with NGINX?

Tags: php, ruby, nginx, fastcgi, erb

Is there a way to simply send a erb file to a ruby parser get the answer back and send it to client with NGINX? Without all the passenger stuff? It should be easy i guess. I DON'T want to use any rails stuff, don't tell me i should use rails etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a script to do this two years ago, called [ruby-cgi](https://gist.github.com/256121), in response to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1901772/231245). I believe it does exacty what you want. Just set it up the same way you would set up other CGI/FastCGI handlers.

Answer (score 2):

The following gems are available (sorted by feature completeness desc):

[rack-server-pages](https://github.com/migrs/rack-server-pages)

[rhr](https://github.com/grosser/rhr)

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly what I was looking for! Yes logic in the View is wrong, but sometime you just need to fire away some Ruby to the world ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, try [this](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/index.html). But I would highly recommend using Sinatra as it's more like a ruby way of serving web pages like in php